# How to decode function that returns number of 1s of the XOR of (target, a number you choose, and a biased random value)?

Tags: xor

I received this problem and unsure how to figure it out. Apparently it is possible to decode the value correctly 99% of the time.

An example: Suppose the target is 20, and there is a function (let's call it noisy_encode) that will return the number of 1's of the XOR of 20, X, and u. You can specify X, and u will range between 0 to 20, with a bias to 2 with 20% probability (remaining are uniform). You can call noisy_encode with different values as many times as you would like.

Comment: Do I get to observe noisy_encode for many X's? Or do I have to fix a single X?

Comment: Many X's are allowed

Comment: In that case, my answer below works.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set $X=0$. Let $t$ be the target.

noisy_encode returns $t\oplus u$ which will be $t\oplus 2$ about 20% of the time, and look random the rest of the time.  The mode output of noisy_encode will be $t\oplus 2$, and so $\text{mode}\oplus 2$ extracts $t$.

*If instead of XOR, noisy_encode uses AND, we can assume $u$ is completely uniform instead:*

First pick $X = 1$.  Then the first bit of $X \wedge u$ will be the same as the first bit of $u$, then the rest of its bits will be $0$.  Thus $X \wedge u$ is either equal to $0$ or to $X$.  There is a nonzero probability of each of these.

Now consider $X\wedge u\wedge t$.  It will either be $0\wedge t$ or $X\wedge t$. In the first case, the output will be $0$.  In the second case, the output will depend on $t$.  Specifically, the first bit will be the same as the first bit of $t$, then the rest of its bits will be $0$.  Thus, if the first bit of $t$ is $0$, then $X\wedge u\wedge t=0$ *always*.  On the other hand, if this bit is $1$, then $X\wedge u\wedge t$ can be either $0$ or $X$.

If you observe the function many times over and over, you will be able to determine which case you are highly likely to be in.

Repeat this process with $X=2,4,8,16,\cdots$ to get all the other bits of $t$.

Comment: If X=1, wouldn't the first digit of XOR(X,u) be the opposite of the first digit of u?

Comment: You are right, I read XOR as AND.

Comment: I fixed my answer.